# MongoDB EmbedsMany Query

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

So I'm using loopback to create a RESTful node.js API. I'm using mLab for my database. I'm trying to query data that is embedded inside of my Account model.

An Account model has a property called favorites which has an array of Songs.

Here is an example:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "58512c1b7c05c491b2cff1f6"
},
"firstName": "Matt",
"lastName": "Thomas",
"username": "mattietea",
"password": "$2a$10$dcquPHK48H5Q7FcaTyzgf.vnrUOgKpBENS9fSa0hjoaASs0uyOWba",
"email": "mattcthomas@me.com",
"_favorites": [
    {
        "title": "Ellusive & Eljay - Like This Before...",
        "artist": "Ellusive",
        "audio": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/236100069/stream?client_id=90d140308348273b897fab79f44a7c89",
        "image": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000145902859-5467c0-t500x500.jpg",
        "download": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/236100069/download",
        "url": "https://soundcloud.com/iamellusive/like-this-before",
        "created": {
            "$date": "2016-12-13T19:00:50.136Z"
        },
        "genres": {
            "hipHop": 100
        },
        "id": "5850456247ef7e110099748b"
    },
    {
        "title": "Dazed and Confused",
        "artist": "Sir Skiff",
        "audio": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/103322663/stream?client_id=90d140308348273b897fab79f44a7c89",
        "image": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000054154948-m9cwii-t500x500.jpg",
        "download": null,
        "url": "http://soundcloud.com/skiffmusic/dazed-and-confused",
        "created": {
            "$date": "2016-12-13T08:49:59.128Z"
        },
        "genres": {
            "hipHop": 100
        },
        "id": "584fb637fbf7df995f4341d3"
    },
    {
        "title": "Runnat",
        "artist": "Rory Fresco",
        "audio": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/258497600/stream?client_id=90d140308348273b897fab79f44a7c89",
        "image": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000157594908-cu10q4-t500x500.jpg",
        "download": null,
        "url": "http://soundcloud.com/roryxxx/runnat-2",
        "created": {
            "$date": "2016-12-13T08:50:52.397Z"
        },
        "genres": {
            "hipHop": 100
        },
        "id": "584fb66cfbf7df995f4341d4"
    },
    {
        "title": "Breathe (Prod. by Yuri Beat$)",
        "artist": "Chiddy Bang",
        "audio": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/106182458/stream?client_id=90d140308348273b897fab79f44a7c89",
        "image": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000055716908-f9qdau-t500x500.jpg",
        "download": null,
        "url": "http://soundcloud.com/chiddybang/breathe-prod-by-yuri-beat",
        "created": {
            "$date": "2016-12-13T08:32:36.447Z"
        },
        "genres": {
            "hipHop": 100
        },
        "id": "584fb224fbf7df995f4341ce"
    }
]
```

}

I have an endpoint set up which returns all the favorites

```
api/Accounts/{id}/favorites
```

But I can't seem to query them. When I query all the songs from `api/Songs` it works but not when I query favorites.

The query I'm using is:

```
{'order': 'created DESC'}
```

I've tried multiple other queries, and none work.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you access '_favorites' array when you query api/Accounts/{id}? Something like "responseObject._favorites"?

Comment: Yup. Just ran `{"fields": {"_favorites": true}, "order": "created DESC"}`. It returns the favorites array but I still can't order it

Comment: I dont know whats happening. Haha I'm going to just get the array and run .reverse() on it for now. I'll post something if I figure it out.